# R warning in if statement

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a loop that runs through a dataframe and corrects incorrect values (EG comedies made by universal inflated their worldwide gross, multiplying it by 1.1 and comedies made by paramount inflated their domestic gross by $0.8) The dataframe specifies the movies, genre, studio, and the gross in different columns

```
for (i in 1:nrow(movie_data)) {
  movies <- movie_data[i,]
  if (distributor == "Universal") {
    if (genre == "Comedy") {
      movies$worldwide_gross <- movies$worldwide_gross / 1.1
    } 
  } else if (distributor == "Paramount") {
    if (genre == "Comedy") {
      movies$domestic_gross <- movies$domestic_gross - 0.8
    } else if (genre == "Drama") {
      movies$domestic_gross <- movies$domestic_gross - 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

what would be causing my error?

Comment: Could you perhaps share the specific text of the warning?

Comment: Why are you dividing for `worldwide_gross` and subtracting for `domestic_gross` ? Shouldn't both of them have the same operation? Also maybe a vectorised solution is possible for this instead of `for` loop. Can you share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The looping here is not really necessary or idiomatic for R. More typically, you'd use something like `movies$worldwide_gross <- movies$worldwide_gross * ifelse(movies$distributor == "Universal" & movies$genre == "Comedy", 1/1.1, 1)` and that would automatically be applied to all rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need a `for loop` to achieve what you want. It's difficult to know, though, if you don't actually share a toy example of your data. `dput(head(movies))` would do it.

With `data.table` the operation could be quite simple:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(movies)

movies[distributor == "Universal" & genre == "Comedy", 
       worldwide_gross := worldwide_gross / 1.1]

movies[distributor == "Paramount" & genre == "Comedy", 
       domestic_gross := domestic_gross - 0.8]

movies[genre == "Drama", 
       domestic_gross - 1.2]
```

Comment: the assignment specifically states we must use a loop to do it

Comment: It wasn't stated it was an assignment. If it was an assignment, it'd be a good idea if you showed some additional effort to solve _your_ homework, or at least it followed the guidelines explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823). Also, as pointed out in a comment by @Jon Spring, loops aren't idiomatic to R, a highly vectorized language.

Comment: @Ian, that's interesting since in R conditional vector assignment should not need a loop. Advise your instructor or program. R maintains vector/matrix/data frame objects for blockwise, vectorized handling. Teaching otherwise may be a disservice to students of R.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, there are obviously better and more optimised ways to do this. (`case_when` from `dplyr`, `ifelse`) but if you have to explicitly use a `for` loop, you can subset the row value with an index and then check for various conditions.

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(movie_data))) {

   if (movie_data$distributor[i] == "Universal" & movie_data$genre[i] == "Comedy")
      movie_data$worldwide_gross[i] <- movies$worldwide_gross[i]/ 1.1
   else if (movie_data$distributor[i] == "Paramount") {
          if (movie_data$genre[i] == "Comedy") {
            movie_data$domestic_gross[i] <- movie_data$domestic_gross[i] - 0.8
      } else if (movie_data$genre[i] == "Drama") {
            movie_data$domestic_gross[i] <- movie_data$domestic_gross[i] - 1.2
     }
   }
 }
```